# Not able to get real time data with Alpaca API

Tags: python, api, rest, finance

I'm trying to make a real time graph for plotting stock data but I can't get .get_position to work. The error message I get is **APIError: position does not exist** and **404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://paper-api.alpaca.markets/v2/positions/AAPL**. If I follow the link directly I get a forbidden message.

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import count
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import threading
import time

api_key = '<API_KEY>'
api_secret = '<SECRET_KEY>'
base_url = 'https://paper-api.alpaca.markets'

api = tradeapi.REST(api_key, api_secret, base_url, api_version='v2')

account = api.get_account()

def stock_grabber():
        global position
        SYMBOL = 'AAPL'
        try:
            position = api.get_position(symbol=SYMBOL)
        except Exception as exception:
            if exception.__str__() == 'position does not exist':
                position = 0
                print(position)
def threadz():
    while True:
        x = threading.Thread(target=stock_grabber)
        x.start()
        time.sleep(0.4)

t = threading.Thread(target=threadz)
t.start()

stock_grabber()

x = []
y = []

index = count()

def animate(i):
    x.append(next(index))
    y.append(position)
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x, y)
             
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=400)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()```
````

Comment: Off-topic: You might want to remove your secret key when asking questions. This is a public forum and someone might misuse it.

Comment: U make a strong argument

Comment: The forbidden message is due to the request missing the API key and secret. Replace the key/secret and try the following curl:
curl -X GET -H "APCA-API-KEY-ID: {YOUR_API_KEY_ID}" -H "APCA-API-SECRET-KEY: {YOUR_API_SECRET_KEY}" https://paper-api.alpaca.markets/v2/positions/AAPL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently discovered that I am dumb. What I was trying to do was to get the real time price not the position.

instead of

```
position = api.get_position(symbol=SYMBOL)
```

use

```
position = (api.get_position('SYMBOL'))
realprice = position.current_price
```

Also the forbidden message was because I was on school wifi